# fakeroot - safe to have on systems?

Tags: linux

I had never heard of [fakeroot](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fakeroot) before but I was compiling a package that wants it as a dependency.  The man page tries to be reassuring but should I be comfortable with this on my systems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

Fakeroot does what it can to pretend to the called process that it's root, but does not (cannot) grant any additional privileges, so no security holes are opened by installing or using it.

Comment: In fact is prevent excessive usage of the "real" root. The most common usage in my own experience is for building Linux packages (i.e. .deb or .rpm), so developers (or their build system automation) don't need to run as root to build a package.

Comment: Also the fact that you as a normal user can download and compile it and get a fully functional `fakeroot` means that it can't open any holes not already there (since that shows that a normal user already has power to do whatever `fakeroot` does).